# Flow meter behavior depending on fluid type?

Tags: density, flow, viscosity

I need design a program which calculates flow rate of a FC-3283 fluid using turbine flow meter.

Basically, there is a rotor inside the device which rotates perpendicular to the direction of the flow(axis of rotation is in the direction of flow).

However, the factory calibration surroundings limits us from using such fluid, so the calibration should be done with water.

The flow meter works by producing pulse output whose frequency is directly proportional to the speed of the rotor which is then proportional to the flow rate.

I am not really a physics expert, but I believe that the relationship between the rotation speed and flow rate depends on the physical property of the fluid to be measured.

I think it has something to do with viscosity or density.

The water has viscosity of 0.99 cSt and density of 0.998 g/cm3

The FC-3283 has viscosity of 0.82 cSt and density of 1.83 g/cm3

Given the same flow rate, which fluid will make the rotor rotate faster, and how can I determine the mathematical relationship?

Thank you!!

Comment: The only reliable way to do this is to build a test rig using the FC-3283 fluid and use that to calibrate your flow meter. I'm surprised you're allowed to proceed without having done this.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes. I am surprised also. However, the calibration facility is outside of our company, which outsourced the electrical component to us. They keep insisting that it should be done without the actual fluid because the fluid is expensive...

Comment: I agree with @JohnRennie .   Even if you were to come up with a model, you would have to validate it by running an experiment ... with the the fluid. Too much risk just accepting a model.